# The variables in the orginal file are organized by row. How can R read it correctly?

Tags: r, read.csv, import-from-csv

I have to deal with data organized by row. So, R reads observation as variables and variables as observation. I have tried to transpose using function t() but R changed all data to character.

The original file is a .csv one.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show a small erproducible example and expected output

Comment: A column can only be a single type, so R will automatically convert everything to character if there are any non-numerical values.  You could just convert them back to numeric after doing the `t()`.  Or you could save the transposed df as a temporary file and read it back in again, and let R have another go at guessing the column types.

Comment: Great. Thank you!